# Were notifications for favorites changed?

Tags: support, notifications, bookmarks

Before, I was getting a lot of notifications for activity on questions in my favorites.

Now, it seems that even if there are new comments, the favorites notification in my user page isn't marked.

Has there been a change in the last month or so to how notifications about favorites are delivered?

Comment: When were you getting notifications for your favorite questions? I've never got any

Comment: @alamoot there's an inner tab in your user page

Comment: right, this makes sense. I thought you meant you were getting notifications on the "Recent Inbox Messages" at the top